# LINQ Remove and then foreach iterate or for iterate and remove in loop?

Tags: c#, linq, loops

I have been tasked with maintaining some legacy code. My predecessor was, at least in my opinion, very experienced with C#. However, I have noticed some strange code left by him. Take this for example:

```
Storage.Clients.RemoveAll(x => x == null || x.IsOutdated());
foreach(Client client in Storage.Clients) {
    //do something
}
```

The list HAS to be cleaned of null and outdated clients, but it seems to me that it would be more efficient if done like this:

```
for(int i = 0; i < Storage.Clients.Count; i++) {
    if(Storage.Clients[i] == null || Storage.Clients[i].IsOutdated())
        Storage.Clients.RemoveAt(i);
    else
       //do something
}
```

My reasoning here is that instead of iterating twice (once in RemoveAll, and then in foreach), it only iterates once, potentially doubling performance. Am I missing something here? As I said, the fact that my predecessor was experienced made me unsure.

Comment: The minimal (if any) performance improvement might not be worth the sacrifice of readability.  That may be why your predecessor did it that way.

Comment: Your code will remove elements while iterating reducing the list size, this will skip elements because `Clients[i]` is now referring to another object. Also note that the first code is `O(2n)=O(n)` while yours is `O(n)`, the improvement is not noticeable.

Comment: @FedericoDipuma hit the nail on the head. Efficiency is not a factor with a once vs twice iteration. Only worry about improving if you can lower by a factor, such as O(n) -> O(logn). Depending on your data obviously, there is likely not much of a point.

Comment: @FedericoDipuma No, the first code is O(n + m), while the second code is O(n^2 + m) (in this case n is the number of items in the start, and m is the number of items that are not outdated).  The first code *isn't* performing twice the operations, the second code is performing **n** times *more* operations.

Comment: @lloyd Doing twice as much work very often *is* relevant.  Unless your data sets approach infinity something being *half* the time is *very* relevant to lots of real world practical problems, even if the Big O is the same.  That said, as mentioned, the second case is a lot slower, on the order of *n times* slower, in fact (for a large data set).

Comment: If you were going to implement it that way you should probably count backwards, because a removal, will cause you to skip the element replaced in it's spot

Comment: @Servy You are right, didn't thought about `RemoveAt` being `O(n)` itself.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What's faster, to run one lap around a mile long track, or to run two laps around a half mile long track?  Do you think that doing two laps around a half mile track will take twice as long?

Having two loops, each doing half as much work as a single loop doing all of it, doesn't result in twice as much work.  You'll have a little bit more overhead of the actual iteration logic, but that's *very* trivial in almost all contexts.  Typically (and this appears to be the case here) the actual work done in the body of loops will greatly overwhelm the amount of work it takes for the actual loop itself (incrementing the loop variable, checking if the loop is done, etc.).

In actuality, in your example the original code is *much* faster.  When you call `RemoveAt` it needs to re-order every single item in the last after the removed item, so if you call it N times that's performing N reorders of (on average) half of the items; you end up moving the same item down by a little bit over and over.  When you call `RemoveAll` it can remove all of the items all at once, and them move *all* of the items down by as much as needed at all once, dramatically reducing the number of reorders of the item in the list, turning an O(n^2) operation into an O(n) operation.

As mentioned in Aomine's answer, you also have a bug in your implementation that doesn't adjust the loop index when you remove an item, so you'll need to fix that before any other considerations can even be made.

There's also a semantic difference between the two, which may or may not be relevant.  It's possible that the program will behave differently if "do something" looks at the list and would be affected by whether or not the outdated items had been removed from it.  (Probably not relevant here, but in general, when considering combining loops, you need to consider if it's actually important that all of the first type of operation be applied to every item before any of the second type of operation be performed.)

Comment: Thank you. I have been trying to find ways to increase performance, but it seems that I might have gone way overboard.

Comment: That being said, is there a way to get better performance in this case? For most of the time, the clients are not outdated, and the loop is iterated over quite often.

Comment: @Yard1 The first option is the *dramatically superior* option, in both performance and correctness, even if you fix the bugs in the latter approach, it's much slower.  So no, just use the original code.  There's nothing wrong with it at all.  If it's actually a bottleneck (which seems unlikely to me, but if it really is) then the whole thing likely needs to be redesigned to avoid *having* to constantly do this work, rather than being able to do it faster.

Comment: Alright, will do. Thanks. It is not a bottleneck, and due to the specifics of the project this loop has to be ran constantly, but I am trying to squeeze as much performance as possible here - clearly, I need to be more careful. Thanks again for your help!

Answer (score 2):

Your approach is error prone as you're removing items while iterating over the collection, which means there is a possibility that you're not removing all the necessary elements because some of them could get skipped whereas your predecessors approach would work as expected.

Comment: The item following an item that is removed won't be handled at all; it'll either not be removed, if it should be removed, or not be processed, if it should be processed.

Answer (score 2):

Your new code will not work. The problem will be if your list has, for instance, 3 items in it (item[0] = A, item[1] = B, item[2] = C)

Your inspect item A (item '0'), decide to remove it.

This decreases the size of the list to 2, and the list now contains (item[0] = B, item[1] = C)

Increment the counter to 1, and do the second iteration of the loop, which in this case item[1] = C

Bug:
You never inspected item B

Comment: Honestly, I have no idea why I missed that. Must be the lack of sleep. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I guess your question should compare against this:

```
Storage.Clients.RemoveAll(x => {
    if (x == null || x.IsOutdated()) return true;

    //do something

    return false;
});
```

It might be a little faster, but I don't think it worths because of readability and other problems pointed by other answers here.